# ASP.Net MVC ADAL TokenCache ignoring AfterAccess BeforeAccess

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, adal

The app has been running great for months, but yesterday had an issue with my dev computer (fall creators update) so checked out the code on my laptop and went to work.  However now I am running into an issue where the app is not writing the token to the cache database.  Adding some breakpoints to

```
void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
```

methods I can see they are never being hit.  My code is identical to the sample code here (except line 14, has a different name)

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/Utils/TokenDbCache.cs

My Startup.Auth.cs is the same as the below (I copied and pasted to test)

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

I have another app which uses almost the identical authentication and it works fine, I can watch it hit this line in the Startup.Auth

```
AuthenticationResult result = await
authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
context.Code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId);
```

then it runs BeforeAccessNotification, BeforeWriteNotification, AfterAccessNotification and works great.

But in the non working app it runs none of the above methods even though everything looks like it should.

[image]

Any ideas?  I am at a total loss.

Comment: Can you compare the working application and the not working one to confirm the difference ?

Comment: @c2h0 - can you set a breakpoint on your cache's constructor? From what you have described, it looks like there is something on the entity framework level (i.e. fail to contact the DB?' so the cached information could not be retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, the issue turned out to the key="ida:GraphUrl" in my web.config was removed (no idea how) so "ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId" in

```
AuthenticationResult result = await
authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
context.Code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId);
```

was null, overlooked it as I assumed

```
catch (AdalException ex)
```

would have caught that.